# iOS 7: delete a location from the weather application

Tags: ios

I would like to delete a location from the weather app in iOS 7.

If I tap and hold I can rearrange the order and the '+' sign allows me to add one.

Swiping left-to-right as in previous versions does not work.

How can a location be removed from the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a common interaction on iOS : Swipe to the left.

Swipe the location to the left, the delete button will appear.

But this does not work on the one that is at the top of the screen if your letting it use your current location

Swipe the location to the left IN LIST MODE. Then a red square delete button appears on the right edge. Tap it and the location is gone.

Comment: My bad, I only tried in the other direction. Thanks

Comment: You can mark it as solved ;)

Comment: In 5 minutes :-) (there is a minimum time, but I will)

Comment: This feature seems to be way too usable for people to figure out ;)